about details of accumulate transform in c++11
I encountered some problems when learning the accumulate function of c++11:
I know that the third parameter of this function needs to receive a clear type and act on the calculation. I tried to let it use the default int type for testing so as to observe the type conversion that occurs. As shown below, I use 0 as the third parameter input, hoping that it will recognize the sum type as int. I expect the calculation process should be (-9) + (3) = -6
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    std::vector<double> v = {-9.4, 3.3};
    
    std::cout << std::accumulate(v.cbegin(), v.cend(), 0) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}


The output result is not what I expected. In fact, it should be a type conversion, but it is not the value -6 I want. The output result is -5. I searched for some information but did not solve this problem. I also conducted other tests in the process. I am not sure whether this error occurs in the conversion process of floating point numbers. I hope someone can help me solve it or give me some methods to check this error.
I tried some things and I got the correct answer unexpectedly after swapping the initial values, but I still don't know why.

On each step, the algorithm adds up int and double, then converts the result to int. The addition is done in floating point. So, int(0 + (-9.4)) == -9. Then int(-9 + 3.3) == int(-5.7) == -5

Details and possible implementations are in the manual std::accumulate

std::accumulate(v.cbegin(), v.cend(), 0) call is roughly equivalent to
int acc = 0;
for (double elem : v) {
  acc = acc + elem;
}

Note that acc + elem adds up an int and a double. Under the standard arithmetic promotion rules, the left argument is promoted to double, the result is of type double; then the assignment converts it to int.
In other words, acc = acc + elem is computed as
acc = int(double(acc) + elem);

and not as
acc = acc + int(elem);

as you appear to expect.
So then
int(0 + (-9.4)) == int(-9.4) == -9
int(-9 + 3.3) == int(-5.7) == -5

And that's the outcome you observe. QED.
